# AngularJS get dom element from string

Tags: angularjs, dom

I have a string containing html code, I want to get from it elements by css selectors like I do with angular.element without displaying it on the page.

How can I do that ?

**EDIT**

for instance, I have this variable:

```
var s = '<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>';
```

Is there any way to get the div wih id='world' ? like:

```
s.function('#world');
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific and put and example of code, that would helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var s = "<div id=\"thing\">Hello</div>";
var d = new DOMParser();
var p = d.parseFromString(s, "text/html");
var t = p.getElementById('thing');
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = s;
var t = div.querySelector('#thing')
```

Comment: can this be done with angular ? I think it would be much simpler

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `var div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = s; var t = div.querySelector('#thing')`

Comment: @Burawi What's complicated about that? You don't want the nodes on the document, but you want to access them with angular?

Comment: @Burawi, Angular connects to your actual document, so the syntax sugar for dom elements only connects to the main document.